# ember js - Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

i face this error when saving data to api

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('firstName', a) to the 'content' property of object proxy <>: its 'content' is undefined
```

below is my code

```
import Ember from 'ember';


export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isValid: Ember.computed(
        'email',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'twitter',
        function() {
            return !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('email')) &&
            !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('firstName')) &&
            !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('lastName')) &&
            !Ember.isEmpty(this.get('twitter'));
        }
        ),
    actions:{
        save: function() {
            if (this.get('isValid')) {
                var _this = this;
                this.get('model').save().then(function(friend) {
                    _this.transitionToRoute('friends.show', friend);
                });
            } else {
                this.set('errorMessage', 'You have to fill all the fields');
            }
        },
        cancel: function() {
            this.transitionToRoute('friends');
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Ember is telling you that the content property of the controller is not set, did you set the model in the route model hook? please add the code for your route.

Comment: I got this error. Turned out I had duplicate controller.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use ObjectController. Use simply Ember.Controller.extend.

Comment: I don't think there is anything particularly wrong with using `Ember.ObjectController`; at least in the current version 1.8.0. However, moving towards Ember 2.0 Controllers will be deprecated, essentially replaced by components (I believe)

Comment: Well, for smooth transition to Ember 2.0 It would be wise to switch to `Ember.Controller`, and create the model  attribute in a component. But for the current versions `Ember.ObjectController` should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I see this on the [ember-cli-101 book](https://leanpub.com/ember-cli-101). I encountered the same issue myself. It's likely that you are not properly setting the model attribute in your route. Based on the book, the error either occurs in the `edit` or `new` route.

if your `router.js` looks like this:

```
...
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('friends', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('show', { path: ':friend_id' });
    this.route('edit', { path: ':friend_id/edit' });
  });
});
...
```

the `friends/index` route needs to set the `model` attribute:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('friend');
  },
});
```

and the `friends/new` route needs to set the `model` in a different way:
    import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('friend');
  },
});
```

For anyone not familiar with the book (mentioned above) the question is from code that is in the book, which is why I referenced it. In most cases, if you get this issue it is likely because you forgot to or  did not set up the model attribute correctly in the appropriate route.

Comment: I'm getting this error on the edit route. I've defined the model in `routes/friends/edit` as such `model: function(params) { return this.store.find('friend', params.friend_id); }` but I'm still getting an error when I hit the cancel button from the edit page. Any pointers?

Comment: @DavidBecerra the edit route doesn't actually need this model hook. `routes/friends/edit.js` should just have the `export default Ember.Route.extend({});` the model hook you showed above should be in the `routes/folders/index.js`. If this doesn't solve the issue, do you have the code repo hosted on github?

Comment: About a second after I posted I realized my mistake. In the controller I was using `this` instead of `this.get('model')`. So I had `this.transitionToRoute('friends.show', this)` vs. `this.transitionToRoute('friends.show', this.get('model'))`.